# How much does Raku's Promise construct share in common with JavaScript's Promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, raku, rakudo

I'm learning asynchronous programming in JS and I couldn't help but noticed both JS and Raku has some construct for asynchronous programming with the same name, however I'm uncertain to what extent the knowledge from one can transfer to the other. I tried reading [JS to Raku](https://docs.raku.org/language/js-nutshell) but the section about [async programming](https://docs.raku.org/language/js-nutshell#Asynchronous_programming) is mostly barren.

For example, is it possible to do something like this in Raku?

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Or something like this if I want to create my own promises?

```js
function getLanguages() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const success = Math.random() >= 0.5;
            if (success) {
                const languages = ['js', 'perl', 'python', 'raku'];
                resolve(languages);
            }
            else {
                reject(new Error('No languages'));
            }
        }, 0);
    });
}

getLanguages()
.then((languages) => {
    console.log(languages);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Raku `Promise` plays the same role as a JavaScript one: it models an operation that may complete asynchronously, with the completion either being successful or erroneous. The API is, however, different, so as to fit in with the Raku language more generally.

In Raku we say that a `Promise` is either kept (successful completion) or broken (erroneous completion), instead of rejected or resolved. I'm not really sure why that wasn't the case in JavaScript; I've literally never told a person that I've resolved my promise to them!

One can make a new `Promise` using `my $p = Promise.new`, but it does not take a function. Rather, one calls `$p.keep($value)` or `$p.break($error)`. These are actually short for `$p.vow.keep($value)` and `$p.vow.break($error)`, and if returning the `Promise` object from an API of some kind, it's usually wise to [obtain the vow - the exclusive right to keep or break the `Promise`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Promise#method_vow), before returning it.

One can use `.then`, noting that it only takes one function and this is passed the `Promise` itself, and `.result` is used to access the result; trying to access the result of a broken `Promise` will rethrow the exception.

As in JavaScript, using `await` instead of `.then` is generally preferred. Unlike in JavaScript, there's no `async` keyword in Raku: you can `await` anywhere! So long as you're on a thread pool thread, the entire callstack is saved away and the thread freed up to work on something else, until such a time that the `Promise` is kept and the continuation is scheduled. As in .Net, you might end up on a different thread after an `await`. You can `await` on a non-pool thread (such as the main thread), and then it's a blocking wait on the `Promise`.

Since `Raku` has had `Promise` in the standard library from the first release, asynchronous built-ins are provided entirely in terms of `Promise` (and `Supply` for streams of asynchronous values). So the `setTimeout` equivalent is `Promise.interval($seconds)`, for example.

Overall: the rough idea of what a `Promise` is in Raku will serve you well, but there's a different API and different idioms to pick up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, jnthn! You've done a great job at helping me bridge the gaps among these concepts. Admittedly I've always struggled to wrap my head around concurrency and asynchrony so it will take some time to sink in.

I couldn’t agree more about the naming. I suppose using `keep` and `break` as the conventional name meant that the name `break` would collide with the keyword `break`.

Answer (score 7):

I would advise reading the follow pages in the Raku docs :

- [Promise](https://docs.raku.org/type/Promise)
- [Concurrency](https://docs.raku.org/language/concurrency)

Note that Raku doesn't have a built library for doing web requests but there are a few options.

- [LWP::Simple](https://raku.land/zef:dwarring/LWP::Simple)
- [HTTP::UserAgent](https://raku.land/github:sergot/HTTP::UserAgent)
- [HTTP::Tiny](https://raku.land/zef:jjatria/HTTP::Tiny)

All of these are make blocking requests but a simple `start` will turn the request into a `Promise` you can chain off. You may also want to checkout [Cro](https://cro.services/) which is a full library for building both client and server side systems that are asynchronous from the ground up.

I hope that's enough to get you started. Good luck.

Comment: I've read my fair share of those doc pages but I haven't taken the leap yet haha. I think it'd be nice to have a page of problems that would benefit from Raku's concurrency and possible solutions. However I understand it's hard to appeal to both beginners and experienced programmers in the docs.

I'll take a look at those libraries, and start playing around while reading the docs.

Thanks a lot, Scimon!

Comment: There's also [`HTTP::Tinyish`](https://raku.land/zef:skaji/HTTP::Tinyish)  which reportedly can work asynchronously ( using `promise`s ), as well as synchronously.  Both `Str` and `Buf` are supported, however unlike its P5 namesake, the Raku module "Currently only supports `curl`.'

Answer (score 3):

For an introduction to concepts of Parallelism, Concurrency and Asynchrony in Raku, I suggest [Jnthn's talk.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpqnNCx7wVY)